# How to mark deep nested FormArray fields as dirty or touched (Form Validation) in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Trying to mark deep nested form array fields as dirty and show error messages on the form but nothing seems to work. Code below.

The Json represensation of the form is below

```
{ 
  "custom_label_mappings": { 
     "store_id": "", 
     "custom_labels": [{ 
          "title": "", 
          "custom_label_name": "", 
          "custom_label_patterns": [{
              "custom_label_value": null, 
              "overwrite_existing_value": true,                                                    
              "custom_label_conditions": [{ 
                  "logical_operator": "and", 
                  "search_criteria": "", 
                  "operator_rule": null,
                  "pattern_value1": "", 
                  "pattern_value2": "" 
           }] 
        }] 
     }] 
  } 
}
```

The following is the FormGroup

```
_form: FormGroup

setCustomLabels(){
    this._form = this._fb.group({
        custom_label_mappings: this._fb.group({
            store_id: ['', [Validators.required]],
            custom_labels: this.buildCustomLabelsArray()
        })
    });
}

buildCustomLabelsArray(): FormArray{
    this.custom_labels = this._fb.array([
        this.buildCustomLabelsGroup()
    ]);

    return this.custom_labels;
}

buildCustomLabelsGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
        title: ['', Validators.minLength(1)],
        custom_label_name: '',
        custom_label_patterns: this.buildCustomLabelsPatternsArray()
    })
}

buildCustomLabelsPatternsArray(): FormArray{
    this.custom_label_patterns =  this._fb.array([
        this.buildCustomLabelsPatternsGroup()
    ])

    return this.custom_label_patterns;
}

buildCustomLabelsPatternsGroup(): FormGroup{
    return this._fb.group({
        custom_label_value: [],
        overwrite_existing_value: true,
        custom_label_conditions: this.buildCustomLabelsConditionsArray()
    })
}

buildCustomLabelsConditionsArray(): FormArray{
    this.custom_label_conditions =  this._fb.array([
        this.buildCustomLabelsConditionsGroup()
    ])

    return this.custom_label_conditions;
}

buildCustomLabelsConditionsGroup(): FormGroup{
    return this._fb.group({
        logical_operator: ["and"],
        search_criteria: ['', Validators.required],
        operator_rule: [],
        pattern_value1: ['', Validators.required],
        pattern_value2: ""
    })
}
```

Now the problem is i want to mark **search_criteria** and **pattern_value1** as touched or dirty when the form is being submitted without the form/form fields been touched. ie. touched/mark the form fields as touched/dirty in the component.

Have tried all that i can but to no avail. 
This is what i have now.

```
checkFormValidity(){
    const fmCtrl = (<any>this._form);
    const clmCtl = fmCtrl.controls.custom_label_mappings
    const clCtl = clmCtl.controls.custom_labels

    Object.keys(this._form.controls).forEach(key => {
        this._form.controls[key].markAsDirty();
    });

    Object.keys(clmCtl.controls).forEach(key => {
        clmCtl.controls[key].markAsDirty();
    });

    Object.keys(clCtl.controls).forEach(key => {
        clCtl.controls[key].markAsDirty();
        const clpCtl = clCtl.controls[key].controls['custom_label_patterns'];

        Object.keys(clpCtl.controls).forEach(key => {
            clpCtl.controls[key].markAsDirty();
            const clcCtl = clpCtl.controls[key].controls['custom_label_conditions'];

            Object.keys(clcCtl.controls).forEach(key => {
                console.log(clcCtl.controls[key])
                clcCtl.controls[key].markAsDirty();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

To simplify I made a helper function to set all to the possible 4 states with options

```
export class Helpers {
/**
   * Loop and touch all it has
   *
   * @param {FormGroup} formGroup
   * @param func << function name: [markAsTouched, markAsUntouched, markAsDirty, markAsPristine, markAsPending
   * @param opts
   *
   */
  public static touchAll(formGroup: FormGroup|FormArray, func = 'markAsDirty', opts = {onlySelf: false}): void {
    mapValues(formGroup.controls, (c, i) => {
      if (c instanceof FormGroup || c instanceof FormArray)
        Helpers.touchAll(c, func, opts);
      else
        c[func](opts);
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below lines to achieve and you need to place these lines after the _form is defined.

```
this._form.controls.custom_labels.custom_labels._pristine=true
this._form.controls.custom_labels.pattern_value1._pristine=true
```

Two properties of controls which is used to check the state of the control are

1. pristine
2. untouched

[Source](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#observe-control)

This works and the properties are as shown in the screenshot of the console.log of a FormGroup object
[image]